# HtmlAgilityPack Nodes and Subnodes

Tags: c#, html, .net, nodes, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse complex html using HtmlAgilityPack

```
<tr>
<td width=0%>Artist:</td><td width=23% class='colour'><a href='/p/beatmaplist?q=Akiakane'>Akiakane</a></td>
<td width=0%>Circle Size:</td><td width=23% class='colour'><div class='starfield' style='width:140px'><div class='active' style='width:56px'></div></div></td>
<td width=0%>Approach Rate:</td><td class="colour"><div class='starfield' style='width:140px'><div class='active' style='width:126px'></div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=0%>Title:</td><td class="colour"><a href='/p/beatmaplist?q=FlashBack'>FlashBack</a></td>
<td width=0%>HP Drain:</td><td class="colour"><div class='starfield' style='width:140px'><div class='active' style='width:84px'></div></div></td>
<td width=0%><strong>Star Difficulty</strong>:</td><td width=23% class='colour'><div class='starfield' style='width:140px'><div class='active' style='width:72.9650211334px'></div></div> (5.21)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=0%>Creator:</td><td class="colour"><a href='/u/231111'>Kiiwa<a/></td>
<td width=0%>Accuracy:</td><td class="colour"><div class='starfield' style='width:140px'><div class='active' style='width:98px'></div></div></td>
<td width=0%>Length:</td><td class="colour">3:13 (2:49 drain)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=0%>Source:</td><td class="colour"><a href='/p/beatmaplist?q='></a></td>
<td width=0%>Genre:</td><td class="colour"><a href='/p/beatmaplist?g=4'>Rock</a> (<a href='/p/beatmaplist?la=3'>Japanese</a>)</td>
<td width=0%>BPM:</td><td class="colour">185</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=0%>Tags:</td><td class="colour"><a href="/p/beatmaplist?q=j-pop">j-pop</a> <a href="/p/beatmaplist?q=beren">beren</a> <a href="/p/beatmaplist?q=collaboration">collaboration</a> <a href="/p/beatmaplist?q=collab">collab</a> <a href="/p/beatmaplist?q=boroboro">boroboro</a> <a href="/p/beatmaplist?q=na">na</a> <a href="/p/beatmaplist?q=ikizama">ikizama</a> <a href="/p/beatmaplist?q=niki">niki</a> <a href="/p/beatmaplist?q=niconicodouga">niconicodouga</a> <a href="/p/beatmaplist?q=toysfactory">toysfactory</a> </td>
<td width=0%>User Rating:</td><td class="colour">
<table width="100%" height="20px" style="color:#fff;">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#BC2036;text-align:right;border:solid 1px #82000B;" width="3.37522441652">93</td>
<td style="background-color:#78AB23;text-align:left;border:solid 1px #718F0A;" width="96.6965888689">2,692</td>
</tr>
```

Each tr should be a object with the included td as properties. I. e.

```
public class SongInfo
        {
            public string CS { get; set; }
            public string AR { get; set; }
            public string HP { get; set; }
            public string STAR { get; set; }
            public string LENGTH { get; set; }
            public string BPM { get; set; }
        }
```

so, In this context, it should look like this:

```
CS should be "Circle Size: (starfield style % divided by active  style %)" 
AR should be "Approach Rate: (starfield style % divided by active style %)" 
HP should be "HP Drain: (starfield style % divided by active style %)" 
STAR should be "Star Difficulty: (starfield style % divided by active style %)" 
LENGTH should be "Length: 3:13"
BPM should be "BPM: 185"
```

When I say (starfield style % divided by active style %),
I'm referring to this code:

```
<div class='starfield' style='width:140px'><div class='active'style='width:56px'></div>
```

So in that situation, it should be 2.5 since 140/56 = 2.5

My first thought was something like this:

```
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr"))
{
     foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes("//td[@width]=0%"))
     {

     }
}
```

But honestly, I have no idea how to go with HtmlAgilityPack since I haven't really used it at all.

Is it possible to do what I'm asking?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you tried hard enough, since you lietrally just copy pasted some code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack), without even trying to look into xpath.

A lot of the html code is similar. I made the entire solution for you. Please read it through thoroughly. Also read the [Html Agility Pack documentation](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00839011553420004828) and about [xpath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Your first initial Xpath is wrong. It is suppose to be: "//td[@width='0%']".
You can suffice with "//td"(however the example below uses //td[@width='0%']") and then you must find the  relevant using another method. In the solution below I used the innertext of each

```
public class SongInfo
{
    public string CS { get; set; }
    public string AR { get; set; }
    public string HP { get; set; }
    public string STAR { get; set; }
    public string LENGTH { get; set; }
    public string BPM { get; set; }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SongInfo song = new SongInfo();

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load("da.html");

        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@width='0%']");


        foreach (HtmlNode n in nodes)
        {
            if (n.InnerText.ToLower().Contains("circle size:"))
            {
                song.CS = n.InnerText+ " " + Convert.ToString(AlmostAnything(n.NextSibling));
            }
            if (n.InnerText.ToLower().Contains("approach rate:"))
            {
                song.AR = n.InnerText + " " + Convert.ToString(AlmostAnything(n.NextSibling));
            }
            if (n.InnerText.ToLower().Contains("hp drain:"))
            {
                song.HP = n.InnerText + " " + Convert.ToString(AlmostAnything(n.NextSibling));
            }
            if (n.InnerText.ToLower().Contains("star difficulty:"))
            {
                song.STAR = n.InnerText + " " + Convert.ToString(AlmostAnything(n.NextSibling));
            }
            if (n.InnerText.ToLower().Contains("length:"))
            {
                song.LENGTH = NextSiblingText(n);
            }
            if (n.InnerText.ToLower().Contains("bpm:"))
            {
                song.BPM = NextSiblingText(n);
            }

        }
        PrintSong(song);  
    }

    private static string NextSiblingText(HtmlNode n)
    {
        return n.NextSibling.InnerText;
    }

    private static int AlmostAnything(HtmlNode n)
    {
        string starfield="" , activefield = "";
        HtmlDocument temp = new HtmlDocument();
        temp.LoadHtml(n.InnerHtml);

        foreach (HtmlNode hN in temp.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div"))
        {
            if (hN.GetAttributeValue("class", "not found") == "starfield")
            {
                starfield = hN.GetAttributeValue("style", "style not found");
            }
            if (hN.GetAttributeValue("class", "not found") == "active")
            {
                activefield = hN.GetAttributeValue("style", "style not found");
            }
        }

        double result = ConvertStringToNum(starfield) / ConvertStringToNum(activefield);
        return Convert.ToInt32(result);
    }

    private static double ConvertStringToNum(string s)
    {
        string temp="";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsNumber(s[i]))
            {
                temp += s[i];
                for (i = i + 1; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Char.IsNumber(s[i]))
                    {
                        temp += s[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Convert.ToDouble(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static void PrintSong(SongInfo s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.CS);
        Console.WriteLine(s.AR);
        Console.WriteLine(s.HP);
        Console.WriteLine(s.STAR);
        Console.WriteLine(s.LENGTH);
        Console.WriteLine(s.BPM);
    }


}
```